# Having trouble with the quotes in my vscode snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

```
"shiv and respond": {
    "scope": "html",
    "prefix": "shiv",
    "body": [
        "<!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->"
        "<!--[if lt IE 9]>"
        "<script src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js'></script>"
        "<script src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js'></script>
        "<![endif]-->",
    ],
    "description": "Add shiv and respond"
}
```

I don't understand how to use double quotes around my script tags and also double quotes after src=, single quotes won't work.

Can anyone explain how to solve this please.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to duplicat top 2 lines

Comment: Just escape the double quotes that you want to appear in the final code, like `"<script src=\"https...min.js\"></script>"`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I just saw your answer. I wish I had noticed it a few minutes ago, could have saved my some time :-)